# Continutity of composite implies continuity of one function

Tags: general-topology

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous surjection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, and $g : Y \to Z$ be an arbitrary map from Y to a topological space $Z$. I am to show that $g$ is continuous if $g \circ f$ is continuous.

This is my effort:

Let $U \in Z$ be open. Then by the continuity of the composite, $(g\circ f)^{-1} (U) =: V$ is open in $X$. Also

$$
(g\circ f)^{-1} (U)  = f^{-1}(g^{-1} (U))
$$

and since $f$ is surjective $f(f^{-1}(S)) = S$, so this reduces to

$$
f(V) = g^{-1}(U).
$$
Hence, this seems to boil down to showing that the map $f$ is an *open* map. However, I can only manage to show is that it is *closed* when $X$ is compact and $Y$ Hausdorff, so I think I am missing something crucial here.

Any hints on how to proceed is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuity of a map is also equivalent to the fact that inverse image of any closed set is closed. So your argument works fine if you use closed sets instead of open sets.

[Once you know that inverse image of any closed set under $g$ is closed, take any open set $U$ and note that $g^{-1}(U)=[g^{-1}(U^{c})]^{c}$].

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is continuous, then so is $g \circ f$ as a composition of continuous maps.

OTOH is $g \circ f$ is continuous, then so is $g$: let $C$ be a closed subset of $Z$, then $(g \circ f)^{-1}[C] = f^{-1}[g^{-1}[C]]$ is closed in $X$, so compact, being closed in a compact space. As $f$ is continuous and onto, $$f[f^{-1}[g^{-1}[C]]] = g^{-1}[C]$$

is compact in $Y$ and thus closed (as $Y$ is Hausdorff). And $C$ closed implies $g^{-1}[C]$ closed shows $g$ is continuous.

This property is actually the characterising property $f$ being a *quotient map* and $f$ is closed continuous onto and these are quotient maps as is well-known. An open onto continuous map is also quotient so has the same property as you noted already.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way could be the following: from the above hypothesis $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous, surjective closed map, hence is a quotient map. Now the continuity of $g$ follows form the universal property of quotient maps